# How to setup Change Password button for user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, passwords

I'm using Firebase Authentication in my iOS app, where the users signs up and logs in with an email and password.

If a user wants to change their password at some point, how can I set that up? I'm assuming that I need to connect an existing Firebase method to a `UITextField`. Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Auth has a method called `updatePassword` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#set_a_users_password):

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: password) { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

You'd probably want at least a UITextField (possibly two if you want to have them confirm the value), check that it meets any requirements you may have about being a certain length, including certain characters, etc (you probably have the same logic in your initial signup screen) and then a `UIButton` that triggers the `updatePassword` flow. Presumably since you've already set up your initial login you're comfortable adding these items to a screen and attaching actions to them.

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx! This is exactly what I needed.